# I stopped the make command mid-way, will previous build be affected?

Tags: makefile, build

I built a very big project, which had a number of sub-projects, using make command. It took me 3 hours. Then by mistake (without cleaning the previous build) I re-executed the make command for a few minutes and then stopped it.
Have I ruined my previous build? How does make actually work behind the scenes? Are building the object files done in an atomic and safe manner?

Note: I cannot really run any of my binary files to see if they are broken since that's another lengthy process. I just want to know if I am fine or I have to re-run the make and let it finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to publish this binary as a production version of your commercial product, then I **would not rely on it**, always be 100% sure that you are using a successfully built version of a fully saved and committed code base.

On the other hand, I you need this for debugging purposes, then you could use this! why? because the make system overrides the output binary only once if finishes compiling all the object files and only if it detects changes that requires a relink of the binary:

> After recompiling whichever object files need it, make decides whether to relink edit. This must be done if the file edit does not exist, or if any of the object files are newer than it. If an object file was just recompiled, it is now newer than edit, so edit is relinked.

[*From GNU make: How Make Works*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html#How-Make-Works)

So if you haven't changed your code base, the linker will not relink the binary, leaving it as it was created by the successful build.

Comment: So, as long as a relink has not been triggered the executable files remain the same?

Comment: @A.Mashreghi, unless you have a custom rule that explicitly affects the old binary, it should remain the same as long as the linking operation didn't start